# Generating XML files from SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net

I've just setup my stackoverflow account after I've been using it for a year or so (I managed to get a lot of answers whilst doing my coursework)! Now that I started my first ever programming job I felt the need to be a member.

I am currently trying to generate XML files from SQL Server tables. I found a YouTube video using `FOR XML PATH`, however their XML was simple they were only using one table whilst mine requires a few tables plus in one of the tables I'll have multiple order so the tags needs to be repeated for as many orders the client have.

Ok so here is my question - I didn't find much tutorials online for complex XML files being generated through SQL Server. I am wondering is there alternative ways that are simpler where you can generate well formatted XML files (all the data is stored in 3 SQL Server tables)? If not can anyone direct me to a useful links to learn from so I can try and generate the XML files!

Thanks you all!

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-import-and-export-of-xml-documents-sql-server.  You can run bcp as a process or create a bat file to run from c#.

Comment: Thank you! I will read up about it :-)

Comment: Hi Sophia, hope you could manage your issues. In such cases it is highly recommended to [create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The answer will depend on the actual data... Furthermore there are tons of answers here on SO. Try to search for `APPLY` and `.nodes`.